# Java Robot and KeyEvent in MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, keypress, matlab-guide, awtrobot

I have a question regarding using robot and keyevent in MATLAB

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
robot = Robot;
if isequal(eventdata.Key,'return')  % capture enter 
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  robot.delay(0.1);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
end
```

This block of code performs its function correctly.  However, it create an enter event outside from the form itself.  How do I contain it in the active form or gui only not in other documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by setting focus to the desired figure in addition with some "waiting":

```
figure(myfigureHandle) %set focus to myFigure
pause(1) %wait for a short amount of time
import java.awt.Robot; import java.awt.event.*; SimKey=Robot;... %doing the robot stuff
```

In your case, the pause-command should only be used, when you are within the if-condition.

Hope that helps!